# Need Help Upgrading xml-security-c-2.0.2 Getting Fatal Error

Tags: c++, linux, xml, redhat, xerces

I'm trying to upgrade `xml-security-c-2.0.2`. I extracted the tar file on my linux environment. I exported the following xerces environment variables below before the `./configure` command:

Env variables:

```sh
export xerces_LIBS=/opt/shibboleth-sp/lib

export xerces_CFLAGS=/opt/shibboleth-sp/include

configure command:
./configure --without-xalan --disable-static --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp
```

Once I run make, I get the following error:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.2/xsec'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I.. -I.. -DXSEC_BUILDING_TOOLS  /opt/shibboleth-sp/include    -Wall  -O2 -DNDEBUG -pthread -MT tools/xtest/xsec_xtest-xtest.o -MD -MP -MF tools/xtest/.deps/xsec_xtest-xtest.Tpo -c -o tools/xtest/xsec_xtest-xtest.o `test -f 'tools/xtest/xtest.cpp' || echo './'`tools/xtest/xtest.cpp
In file included from tools/xtest/xtest.cpp:32:0:
**../xsec/framework/XSECDefs.hpp:63:39: fatal error: xercesc/util/XercesDefs.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <xercesc/util/XercesDefs.hpp>''**'
```

For whatever reason it cannot find the source file `XercesDefs.hpp`. This has been an issue for a month or so where we cannot figure out why it isn't finding that source file. When I run a find on this particular file, I get the following path showing it is indeed in multiple locations:

```sh
/opt/build/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/util/XercesDefs.hpp
/opt/shibboleth-sp/include/xercesc/util/XercesDefs.hpp
```

Is there something in the compile process that is making this not work or not pick this up? Should I be exporting something else in order to pick up this file?

We currently have version `xml-security-c-1.7.3` installed on the machine. Would it be easier to use this version? Is there some sort of bug with 2.0.2 or something that needs to be configured from going from version 1.x to 2.x?

This is all to upgrade shibboleth idp, and installing all the needed dependencies prior to Shibboleth build.

```
> current OS version Linux version 4.14.214-118.339.amzn1.x86_64
> (gcc version 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2) (GCC)) #1 SMP
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT:
I've exported my `CXXFLAGS` to point at include however I'm still getting the following error when I issue the make command:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.2'
Making all in xsec
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.2/xsec'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ /opt/shibboleth-sp/include    -Wall /opt/shibboleth-sp/include -O2 -DNDEBUG -pthread   -o xsec-xtest tools/xtest/xsec_xtest-xtest.o libxml-security-c.la /opt/shibboleth-sp/lib   /opt/apache2_4_46/bin
libtool: link: g++ /opt/shibboleth-sp/include -Wall /opt/shibboleth-sp/include -O2 -DNDEBUG -pthread -o .libs/xsec-xtest tools/xtest/xsec_xtest-xtest.o /opt/shibboleth-sp/lib /opt/apache2_4_46/bin  ./.libs/libxml-security-c.so -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/shibboleth-sp/lib
/opt/shibboleth-sp/include: file not recognized: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [xsec-xtest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.2/xsec'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is going on with this?

Comment: `xml-security-c-2.0.2` etc. : The "Scott_Cantor.repo" https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home%3A/Scott_Cantor/CentOS_7/ ..... → → https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home%3A/Scott_Cantor/CentOS_7/x86_64/ .... **repo file** https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home%3A/Scott_Cantor/CentOS_7/home%3AScott_Cantor.repo

Comment: I need the .tar.gz files. Thank you for the response however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHEL 7.2 is the year 2015 update. Current is 7.8 (yum update).

> XercesDefs.hpp: No such file

`xml-security-c-2.0.2` configure will look in `/usr/include, /usr/local/include` ! When you have a "hide away" location, the INCLUDE path must be specified : See `$ ./configure --help`

Example : `CXXFLAGS=-I/opt/shibboleth-sp/include` , I.e. →

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp CXXFLAGS=-I/opt/shibboleth-sp/include
```

Bugs : There are no bugs in xml-security-c-2.0.2 . Will compile without errors in EL 7 ( 3 minutes, g++73 (or with the default g++ ver. 4.8 )).

---

Ref your comment »» I need the .tar.gz files «« : Please follow the link https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home%3A/Scott_Cantor/CentOS_7/ → **src/**

Example `$ bash unPack_rpm.sh xml-security-c-2.0.2-4.2.src.rpm` and you get `xml-security-c-2.0.2-4.2.src/{xml-security-c-2.0.2.tar.bz2 , xml-security-c.spec}`

Script `unPack_rpm.sh` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3d9QqrRhEThYByPDgWEaoxHnqWFWqfE/view?usp=sharing

Get build-deps : `# yum-builddep xml-security-c.spec`

Comment: Thank you for the reponse! I did what you said and while the make process went further I'm still getting the following error:
/opt/shibboleth-sp/include: file not recognized: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [xsec-xtest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.2/xsec'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2